# Is This a Mistake?: Regarding the property $e^x e^y = e^{x+y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, stochastic-processes

My textbook has the following:

$$e^{\lambda(s-1)} e^{\mu (s-1)} = e^{(\lambda+\mu)s-1}$$

This is not in the errata but I felt it should be,

$$e^{\lambda(s-1)} e^{\mu (s-1)} = e^{(\lambda+\mu)(s-1)}$$

My apologies if I made a trivial or silly mistake. I'm checking my work and I simplified to the second equation but if it's the first one would you mind explaining how that is? Thank you.

Again, this does not appear in the errata provided.

Comment: you are correct, there should be parentheses

Comment: You are right. Add your result to the errata :)

Comment: Printer's devil, he forgot brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course since

$$a^x\cdot a^y=a^{x+y}$$

the following is right

$$e^{\lambda(s-1)} e^{\mu (s-1)} =e^{\lambda(s-1)+\mu (s-1)} = e^{(\lambda+\mu)(s-1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{\lambda(s-1)} e^{\mu (s-1)} = e^{(\lambda+\mu)s-1}$$
$$e^{(\lambda+\mu)s} e^{-(\mu +\lambda)} = e^{(\lambda+\mu)s}e^{-1}$$
$$e^{-(\mu +\lambda)} = e^{-1}$$
Only true for
$$\mu  = 1-\lambda$$
But then he would have expressed this like this
$$e^{(\lambda+\mu)s} e^{-(\mu +\lambda)} = e^{s-1}$$
When this is true for all $\lambda,\mu$
$$e^{\lambda(s-1)} e^{\mu (s-1)} = e^{(\lambda+\mu)(s-1)}$$
Depends on the context because first equality may be true in some contexte while the second equality is always true.

Comment: Ah interesting. Well the idea is that we use a Probability Generating Function to confirm that this is poisson with parameter $/mu + \lambda$ but I don't believe it to be accurate if we don't use $(s-1)$.

However, thank you for the insight. With the right conditions you can often find some interesting results. Nonetheless I imagine the book would need to include these requirements.

Comment: Yes @Nicklovn the context has its importance because first equality can be true too...Check all the steps in your book to make sure you didnt miss something. First eqality means  $\lambda+\mu=1$ thats it

Comment: I don't believe so. The Poisson PGF is $G_X (s) = e^{\lambda (s-1)}$

And this is for the poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$

Comment: then maybe it's just a typo ...@Nicklovn